# Giving a name to a div id that holds an erb object id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following div...

```
<div class="list_entries" id="<%= entry.id %>">
```

How might I give the div id a name as well as using the entry.id?

Example for later use in JavaScript...

```
$('#<%= entry.id %>').css("text-decoration", "line-through");
```

This is so I can have a strike through on just one specific entry instead of all of the entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOM IDs must be unique across the entire document. Unless you're using that same entry.id elsewhere for OTHER dom elements, there's no need for prefixes.

That being said, it could be as simple as:

```
<div id="foo<%= entry.id %>">
         ^^^    
$('foo<%= entry.id %>').etc....
   ^^^
```

Comment: Perfect and so simple! Thanks